# How to make Jaspersoft Studio export to xlsx without repeating column header (as JasperReports server does)?

Tags: jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

Jaspersoft Studio exporting to xlsx has this annoying behavior of "paginating" an Excel sheet as if it were a page oriented document.

There is an option in exporter to put one page in each sheet, that's not what I'm talking about. It prints everything in a single sheet, but repeats the column header band (the names of the columns) and page footer band every dozens or rows, as if it were a paginated document like a PDF.

I know it's possible to prevent this because if I run the very same report on JasperReports Server it will work just fine, i.e. will print column header every page if I export to PDF, but will not if I export to xlsx or xls.

I've played with many options for XLS exporter in Jaspersoft Studio and many export [configurations](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html) of the report without success. My Jaspersoft Studio is configured to reproduce what JasperReports Server does in terms of xlsx export, but I don't think any of [these export parameters](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/xls-export-parameters-jasperreports-server) really deal with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

For this I just put `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1` in the "print when" field on the column header properties, then it should only print the column header once. Not sure though about the page footer I'm afraid as I don't use them but imagine that would obviously could/would change.

Comment: Yeah, this works. Another way is to put the column names in the title band instead of column header band. The problem with both approaches is that if I try to export to a page oriented format like PDF, the column names will be missing too, and in this case they are desirable. There must be a way to reproduce the Jasper Server's behavior which is smart enough to know when it should or not repeat column names.

Comment: Yeah I used to do the Title band way but when I figured out the spreadsheet layout it changed my life (very dramatic yes) sorry I’m not sure about PDFs as I don’t convert to those. I hope someone else can help!

Answer (score 0):

[Enable Ignore Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSEqs.png)
Here is what you need: Check the Ignore Pagination in report's properties

Comment: By doing this I get a single page document when exporting to PDF, wich is undesirable. I want to reproduce what jasper server does. Export to pdf and xlsx, the former repeating column names and the latter not. Maybe I'm asking too much, but as I said, jasper server can do it. So it's possible.